# How to load multiply IFC models to viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

our customer has problem with loading multiply IFC models in GuiViewer3D component. It seems all right, he set coordinates to globalOffset (0,0,0). But sometime there is problem with scrolling: There is som lagging, or bad zoom and he can't select some elements in it. It's like some displace in model. Maybe models has no the same base point. How to deal with it ? Is there any solution in Forge ?

Regards,

Milann

Comment: What's the Viewer version? Are you loading very large models? It cloud affect performance.

Comment: He use this version https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js
IFC models has total about 20 MB

Comment: re-reading your question: as you said you can't select, what do you mean? Are you resizing the DIV that contains the Viewer? if so, please call `viewer.resize()`

Comment: @Augusto Goncalves: I link You video, maybe it clear my question. He use DIV, but viewr.resize() not solve problem. https://graitecroumanie.sharepoint.com/:v:/s/graitec_slovakia/EaGo1bcnOJBJhzkFo7OhEVIBB3g5f1aOIuNdUjZupBE5Cw?e=oXHayk

Comment: thanks @Milann. Are you able to try that model with viewer.autodesk.com? trying to determine if this is related with the Viewer or with the way you are using the viewer.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto. In viewer seems all OK. So, how can we solve the problem ? Do You think I send You source code ?

Comment: if you can share the code or a live version, I can take a look. You can use the forge.help at autodesk.com email alias (private)